# MPI Communication Pattern

Tags: mpi

I was wondering if there was a smart way to do this. Let's say I have three nodes, 0, 1, 2. And let's say each node has an array, a0, a1, a2. If the contents of each node is something like

```
a0 = {0, 1, 2, 1}
a1 = {1, 2, 2, 0}
a2 = {0, 0, 1, 2}
```

Is there a clever communication pattern so to move each number to it's corresponding node, i.e.

```
a0 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
a1 = {1, 1, 1, 1}
a2 = {2, 2, 2, 2}
```

The approach I have in mind, would involve sorting and temporary buffers, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way?

Comment: I don't understand--can't you just fill a0 with 0, a1 with 1, etc.?  Presumably there's more to your problem than is shown by your example.  It's also not clear what you mean by "three nodes, 0, 1, 2" and how that relates to the MPI "nodes" (computers) or the 0,1,2 values in your arrays.

Comment: Thanks John. I guess Zulan is on the right path. The three nodes are separate computers. Yes there is more to the problem. I only chose the values in the array in an attempt to make my intention clearer. I guess I failed at that xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MPI_Alltoallv` for this in the following way:

1. Sort the `local_data` (`a`) by corresponding node of each element in increasing order.
2. Create a `send_displacements` array such that `send_displacements[r]` indicates the index of the first element in the `local_data` that refers to node `r`.
3. Create a `send_counts` array such that `send_counts[r]` equals the number of elements in `local_data` that correspond to node `r`. This can be computed `send_counts[r] = send_displacements[r+1] - send_displacements[r]` except for the last rank.
4. `MPI_Alltoall(send_counts, 1, MPI_INT, recv_counts, 1, MPI_INT, comm)`
5. Compute `recv_displacements` such that `recv_displacements[r] = sum(recv_counts[r'] for all r' < r)`.
6. Prepare a `recv_data` with sum(recv_counts) elements.
7. `MPI_Alltoallv(local_data, send_counts, send_displacements, MPI_INT, recv_data, recv_counts, recv_displacements, MPI_INT, comm)`

Comment: Thanks Zulan I guess this is the approach I had in mind (although fleshed out a little more). Is this a typical communication pattern for this kind of probelm?

Comment: I would say this is a very idiomatic way to approach this problem. However, I don't think this is a common problem.