# MPI: Efficient exchange of different amounts of data between all nodes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi

I'm totally new to MPI and have absolutely no idea as to what is efficient.
I have x (x = 2, 4, 8, 16, ...) nodes, each of them with large text files of more than 4 million lines. 
I want to sort these lines using bucket sort, and for that, I want to send the correct lines to each of the nodes (= buckets), meaning I have to send (and receive) from every node to every other node.

Currently my idea is like this:
With my root, I calculate bucket limits that every node has to know so they can send the right lines to the right nodes. I broadcast these limits using MPI_Bcast.
After that, since the count of every set of lines to be send is different, I send the count of lines to be received from every node to every other node using MPI_Isend, MPI_Irecv and MPI_Waitall.
When every node knows how much data it's going to receive from each node, I do the same for the data itself.
The sends and receives are done alternating for each node (process[i] wants to send to process[i+1] first and then receive from process[i-1]).

My code for the send and receive part looks like this:

```
// fill the buffer for the current rank (because data doesn't have to be sent)
buffers[rank] = buckets[rank];

int i, amount, sendIndex, receiveIndex;

// create MPI_Requests
int reqsIndex = 0;
MPI_Request dummyRequest;
MPI_Request reqs[numtasks - 1];
for (i = 0; i < numtasks - 1; i++)
   reqs[i] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

// amounts[i]: Which process receives how much data from the current rank
int* amounts = malloc(sizeof(int) * (numtasks-1));

sendIndex = (rank + 1) % numtasks; // always contains the index of the next process to send data to (starting with [rank + 1])
receiveIndex = (rank + numtasks - 1) % numtasks;  // always contains the index of the next process to receive data from (starting with [rank - 1])
int isSending = 1; // determines if the current process sends or receives data (always sends first)
// alternating send and receive for each process
for (i = 0; i < (numtasks - 1) * 2; i++)
{
    if (isSending) { 
        MPI_Isend(&buckets[sendIndex]->n, 1, MPI_INT, sendIndex, TAG_NUMBER_OF_SENDED_LINES, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &dummyRequest);
        sendIndex = (sendIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        if (sendIndex == rank)
            sendIndex = (sendIndex + 1) % numtasks;
    }
    else {
        MPI_Irecv(&amounts[receiveIndex], 1, MPI_INT, receiveIndex, TAG_NUMBER_OF_SENDED_LINES, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[reqsIndex]); 
        receiveIndex = (receiveIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        if (receiveIndex == rank)
            receiveIndex = (receiveIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        reqsIndex++;    
    }
    isSending = (isSending + 1) % 2; // switch isSending from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1
}

MPI_Waitall(numtasks - 1, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE); // waits for all receives to be finished

// requests reset
reqsIndex = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numtasks - 1; i++)
   reqs[i] = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

sendIndex = (rank + 1) % numtasks; // always contains the index of the next process to send data to (starting with [rank + 1])
receiveIndex = (rank + numtasks - 1) % numtasks; // always contains the index of the next process to receive data from (starting with [rank - 1])
isSending = 1; // determines if the current process sends or receives data (always sends first)
for (i = 0; i < (numtasks - 1) * 2; i++)
{
    if (isSending) {
        MPI_Isend(buckets[sendIndex]->data, buckets[sendIndex]->n * LINE_LENGTH, MPI_BYTE, sendIndex, TAG_LINES, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &dummyRequest);
        sendIndex = (sendIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        if (sendIndex == rank)
            sendIndex = (sendIndex + 1) % numtasks;
    }
    else {
        lineBuffer* lines = allocLines(amounts[receiveIndex]); 
        MPI_Irecv(lines->data, amounts[receiveIndex] * LINE_LENGTH, MPI_BYTE, receiveIndex, TAG_LINES, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[reqsIndex]); 
        buffers[receiveIndex] = lines;
        receiveIndex = (receiveIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        if (receiveIndex == rank)
            receiveIndex = (receiveIndex + 1) % numtasks;
        reqsIndex++;        
    }
    isSending = (isSending + 1) % 2; // switch isSending from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1
}

MPI_Waitall(numtasks - 1, reqs, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE); // waits for all receives to be finished
```

Currently, the send/receive times for each node are very different, some processes taking a much longer time to go through this code than other nodes. Is there something better to use than isend/irecv/waitall, especially considering that everything that is being sent is of different size? 
Cheers. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good first question, but you could still improve it with an [mcve]. Anyway, you can do all this with collectives, giving MPI more opportunities to optimize and expressing your communication in a more abstract way. Please take a look at . On an abstract level, this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37015784/620382). I am hesitant to dupe-vote yet as your question is more specific. Please take a look at the answer and let us know if it helps you.

Comment: @Zulan Thanks a lot for your quick answer and your advice regarding my question. I took a look at the other question and I believe that approach might also work for me. I'll try to implement it and see if I come across any problems I didn't consider. Thank you. :)

Comment: I doubt using collective operations will help. If the amount of data sent from one process to another varies a lot among the processes, it simply means that the algorithm is not suitable for that kind of parallelisation as the parallel efficiency will be limited by the work imbalance.

Comment: @HristoIliev The amount of data to be sent should usually be roughly the same (e.g. if I have two nodes with exactly 4million lines each, one node will end up with 3.9m lines and the other with the rest) - however, I cannot guarantee that as there can be cases where this isn't true - in theory, it is possible that one node has to send all of its data to one other node.

Comment: @Zulan I tried your solution and after a lot of trial and error (I didn't realize that the displacements and such were in bytes...) it works now and it's definitely faster than my code. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Feel free to post that as answer to this question so more people can learn from it.